# Ubuntu 18.04, battery indicator not displaying as well as system saying no battery

Tags: 18.04, battery

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, I originally had Windows 10 running on a microsoft surfacebook 2 and since then have completely wiped windows. Since then I can't find a battery indicator anywhere. Even in my power statistics there is even no tab for it. In another app to look at hardware it says there even is no battery.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing [jakeday's surface-linux kernel](https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface). I've previously used it with a Microsoft Surface 2017, where it fixed the missing battery indicator (among other things). It supports the Surface Book 2 and is relatively straightforward to install when following the instructions in the readme.